# WSO2 ESB 4.8M1 : ResequencingProcessor missing

Tags: design-patterns, wso2, message, esb, eip

It seems that the ResequencingProcessor class (and the associated documentation, e.g. sample_703) is not implemented yet within WSO2 ESB 4.8M1;

According to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SYNAPSE-893, it should be delivered with Synapse v3; furthermore, the resequensing patter is already mentioned in "EIP with WSO2 ESB.

Is it possible in the meantime to get a patch in order to get this feature ? which version of WSO2 ESB will implement synapse 3.x ?

Regards

Dom

Answer (score 1):

According to 4.8.0 M1, 4.8.0 is implemented in 2.1.X.

There is a public jira for given issue [1].

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2379

Comment: OK, thanks; so this feature won't be implemented in synapse 2.1 based ESB 4.8.0 , right ?